# mysqli_close Closes Connection In Present File or All Files?

Tags: jquery, ajax, mysqli, server, call

I have a question that can't find clear answer to it.
mysqli_close() closes connection in file where is present or it closes for the rest of running files too in php?

I have a page with an ajax.php file that runs with jquery at setInterval to update divs data on the page. I guess the problem is getting same ajax file every 5 seconds leaves it open multiple times on the server which may give high load errors after some time. For example after some time I get this error:

> "2020/01/01 12:12:13 [alert] 11106#0: *2321484 socket() failed (24: Too many open files) while connecting to upstream, client: 221.58.112.71, server: myname.com, request: "GET /ajax.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0. 0.1:7080/ajax.php", host: "myname.com", referrer: "https://myname.com/page.php"".

So I think maybe use mysqli_close() to close connections at the end of ajax file, is that enough? and it won't affect the rest of the website like for example causing db connection end on other pages run by users since the ajax load in background?

I know I can increase options in servers to allow more open but I don't think that's a solution if too many users on page loading the ajax file in background if it remains open somewhere.

The ajax call to the ajax.php page is bellow:

```js
setInterval(function() {
  // update details over the website live ajax every 5 seconds
  $.ajax({
    url: 'ajax.php'
  }).done(function(data) {
    $('.ws-time').html(data.ws_time);
    $(".received-messages").html(data.received_messages);
    $(".received-notifications").html(data.received_notifications);
    $(".user_level").html(data.user_level);
  });
}, 5000);
```

Comment: Making an AJAX request to your server every 5 seconds is not a scalable solution and will cause performance issues - as you've discovered. If you need to keep the server and client in close sync use Websockets instead.

Comment: Isn't there a way to close connection to the file at end of file to keep current ajax? Do you know how to do it with websockets?

Comment: The closure should already be happening, but I doubt that the main issue; it's because you're DDOSing yourself

Comment: Your question makes no sense and is unclear. Ajax has nothing to do with closing connection. You don't even need to use `mysqli_close()` at all. This function closes the connection, which you pass as an argument to it. Mysqli connection doesn't belong to any physical file.

Comment: @Dharman Yes but I mean closing the main connection for one file closes for the whole website if it's using same $connect connection i.e. mysqli_close($connect);